# ESP32 Unable to get time form the NTP server

Tags: esp32

I am looking for a method to obtain the time from an NTP server.  I have code that seems to work but have learned that you to put in a delay before printing the date ad time.  My code is based on a suggested solution but it does not work.  I am relatively new to the ESP32 world and may be making a fundamental error.

I am not at all sure what the constant value is.

`while (now < 1510592825)`

Here is the code that I am testing.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <time.h>

const char* ssid     = "xxxxxx";
const char* password = "xxxxxx";

IPAddress local_IP(192, 168, 0, 199);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 254);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet);  
  Serial.println("Connecting to internet");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected");

  time_t now;
  configTime(-5 * 3600, 1800, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
  now = time(nullptr);

  while (now < 1510592825)
    {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
      time(&now);
    }

  struct tm *timeCur;
  timeCur = localtime(&now);

  Serial.println(timeCur->tm_hour);
  Serial.println(timeCur->tm_min);
  Serial.println(timeCur->tm_sec);
}

void loop() {}
```

The connection to the internet works.  The second While loop is never ending.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using static IP for your server, you need to have DNS setting in order to resolve the server name such as "pool.ntp.org".

Here is a code snipper that will work:

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <time.h>

const char* ssid     = "wifi-said";
const char* password = "wifi-password";

IPAddress local_IP(192, 168, 0, 199);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 254);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress dns(8,8,8,8);   // add DNS 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet, dns);
  configTime(-5 * 3600, 1800, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");

  Serial.println("Connecting to internet");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected");

  while (time(nullptr) < 1510592825)
  {
    delay(1);
  }

  time_t now = time(nullptr);
  struct tm* t = localtime(&now);
  Serial.println(t, "%A, %B %d %Y %H:%M:%S");
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it with the same result.  I thought perhaps my device was faulty and tried a new one with the same result.

Comment: How about you comment out the line `  WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet, dns);`? will it work?

Comment: Yes, that worked just fine and will do exactly what I want.  Thank you very much!